# replace text in Sort Box

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, sort

I have renamed the woocommerce sort options to remove the default "Sort by" preceding all of them.

However I would like to rename the text in the box at the top to “Sort by", so that the selected sort option is not displayed, and will only be shown highlighted once the box is opened. The image below shows how by default the selected sort option shows in the top box aswell as in the drop down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter for sort options that you can use, but it looks like there is already a Sort By: Popularity option there. [You can see the filter here.](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0f28a6191076a57ef6576d9196a863bc79499971/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1354)

You may want to check to see if other plugins or your theme are defining where the Sort By text is coming from.

WooCommerce also uses the built-in WordPress translation system, so you may be able to use something like Loco Translate (https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to find the string you want to modify and create a "custom translation", from "Sort By" to "Sort By Popularity".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tom, I forgot I had actually already renamed these to remove "sort by" on all of the options. But what I am wanting to do is show "sort by" only on the selected option, which may be difficult. I'll edit the question to clarify. "Sort by" may need to be a heading, with the selected option appended to it. Not sure if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand what you are looking to do. Can you review this example and let me know if this is getting close to what you are trying to accomplish? https://codepen.io/sixfoot3/pen/oNgNNVm?editors=1010

Comment: I have updated the question again. The main goal is to not list the sort option twice. If the default box text was just “sort by” then the current option wouldnt show twice. Not sure if this is possible though.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site so I can see what is happening specifically in your case? If I have that I can suggest a way to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: Have just added an image showing the selected option showing a second time.